# Spring 3 MVC, stream response asynchronously

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, outputstream, spring-3

I'd like to stream out my content using `OutputStream` or `Writer` from Spring MVC controller method using async solution, i.e. not to block base threadpool used for http requests. As far as I could find is to use `DefferedResult<?>` for async in general. It's fine when you return a view string name but can't think of a way it would work with stream. Could not find anything helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Well you may try to use the WebSocket approach; the cliet is listening for any events, and you simply finish to stream the content in asynchronous mode and then you can pass to the client

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/03/deferredresult-asynchronous-processing.html) you can perform computation in another thread thereby unloded http thread pool.
You can try to combine `DefferedResult` and `byte[]` (DefferedResult) return type(previously registering `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`). So the final method will look like this:

```
@ResponseBody
public DefferedResult<byte[]> foo(HttpServlet response) {
    //set headers using response
    response.setContentType("someContentType");
    ...

    DefferedResult<byte[]> r = new DefferedResult<>();
    executionService.submit(() -> {
       r.setResult(getBytes());
    });
    return r;
}
```

Another option is to combine Defferedresult and ResponseEntity. Do not forget to use it in servlet 3.0+ container

Comment: I'd guess that Spring will end the communication as soon as you setResult, and don't continue to output bytes as a stream. No?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that what you are looking for is the following. Not sure if it blocks the http thread pool though.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public StreamingResponseBody handleRequest () {

        return new StreamingResponseBody() {
            @Override
            public void writeTo (OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    out.write((Integer.toString(i) + " - ")
                                        .getBytes());
                    out.flush();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```